# Eclipse Tomcat projects not updating when published

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to use tomcat integrated with eclipse to test my web apps, but it no longer updates the deployment and continually throws old errors that have since been patched. For example I have an exception:

```
com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:143)
at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
at com.mywebsite.eureka.client.EurekaClient.register(EurekaClient.java:39)
at com.mywebsite.authservice.Init$1.run(Init.java:27)
```

This points to line 39 of EurekaClient, the function register(). This line is blank, and the function no longer exists.

I have tried cleaning the server, republishing, removing and adding the projects, and removing and adding the server but non of this has worked. I have no idea why this is happening and help would be appreciated.

Comment: delete Servers folder on disk?

Comment: That appears to have no effect.

Comment: Do you use maven with some snapshot dependencies ?

Comment: No, all my maven dependencies are the latest stable releases

Comment: Have you done a `mvn clean package` before cleaning the server ? Sometimes, the target/classes folder contains old .class files.